# Installing new nodes in node-red remove dashboard

Tags: node-red

I'm new to node-red. I have just started using node-red/node-red-dashboard and when I install other packages, for some reason node-red-dashboard gets removed. I'm in the .node-red dir when I run npm install.

Ex. npm install node-red-node-sqlite. When finished, I get errors about waiting for missing types to be registers and have to reinstall dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a known bug/feature of npm 5 - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17165

It seems to occur when you run `npm install` without a `package.json` file in place.

As an alternative to running `npm install` manually, you can use the Manage Palette feature of Node-RED to install modules from within the editor. This will ensure a `package.json` file is maintained with an accurate list of additional modules you've installed.

Comment: Looks like this is the case. Thx!